# Your app information could not be saved. Try again - iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When trying to submit my binary I keep getting this error,

> Your app information could not be saved. Try again

In my member center I have an iOS development provisioning profile that is expired but that is for development and should affect me being able to submit binary right?

Comment: Same problem here....

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800116/itunes-connect-submit-for-review-your-app-information-could-not-be-saved-try with same answer.

Comment: @Bartłomiej Semańczyk I'd leave this question closed because there's already an accepted answer, and there's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Apple's problem. 
Give it try in a few hours.